# Custom module Nodejs - Set Property To arguments of anonymous inner function

Tags: javascript, node.js

This module is minimal module that can be used to create server-side code in Nodejs.
Please read the comment in the code to undersrtand what is going on.

I have the following code :

```
import http from 'http';

class Application {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  listen(...args) {
    const server = http.createServer(this.contextBody()).listen(...args)
  }
  contextBody () {
    // Is this ok?
    let req = Object.create(http.IncomingMessage.prototype);
    let res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);
    return function(request, response) {
        // What should I put here? 
        res.statusCode = response['status']
        res.end(response['body']) 
    }
  }
}
export const Maki = new Application();
```

How should the logic in anonymous `function (request, response)` like ?
I have call this module like so :

**The logic should used like this below**

```
import { Maki } from "../lib/application.js";

Maki.contextBody((req, res) => {
    // How can i have the following code to work.
    // this will thrown an error because res was undefined
    // res.status = 200;
    // res.body = "Hello World!"
})
Maki.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server runnig!"))
```

Any help to make this possible please?

Comment: Please insert in the question the full error that you get too, please.

Comment: @MarcusCastanho This is the error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of undefined

Comment: from what I can see, it seems that you are using the parameters for your return function as (request, response) and inside it you are calling res.statusCode. Did you try printing in console what you get when you define the res and req?